# IIS 6.0 preventing PUT & DELETE method types on WCF 4.0 web service calls

Tags: c#, iis-6

I am trying to delete employee from database and I am Using DELETE Verb.
But I have an app that is using WCF 4.0 configure-less setup to make RESTful webservices calls. Everything works fine locally but when pushed to my server all PUT and DELETE requests return a 403 forbidden error.

After searching around I've been unable to find anything that seems to work, and I'm not sure if there is some logs that would help figure this out, I'm not a server guy and apparently neither is my "server guy". So any tips on where to point him or what might be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enable parent paths.

1.Open the IIS Management console,

2.Right click on your website in the sidebar and go to properties.

3.Go to the "Home Directory" Tab

4.In the "applications settings", click on the "configuration" button

5.In the "Applications configuration" Window, there should be a Mappings Tab

6.Simply choose which file extensions you want to have mapped (in my case i wanted ASP to map GET, PUT, POST & DELETE), comma delimited. And thats it, not even a restart required.